# php mysqli error: undefined function mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect to mySQL database using php but getting below error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect

- php version: php 5.3.3
- OS: Redhat 6.8
- mysql server version: 5.1.73

I checked php.ini file but it has no extension for mysql or mysqli

output of `php -m` command shows no reference to mysql or mysqli

I tried below commands to install mysqli

```
sudo yum install php53-mysql
sudo yum install php53-mysqli
sudo yum install php53-mysqlnd
```

but got error as `No package available`

There is no mysqli.so or mysql.so file in `/usr/lib64/php/modules`

There is no mysqli.ini or mysql.ini file in `/etc/php.d/`

What am I missing here?

Comment: it maybe help you : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-native.html

Comment: Well.. you're missing your code for starters...

Comment: did you restart the mysql server after installing?

Comment: mysql server is working properly . mysqli ( php extention ) is not installed

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) says that MySQLi extension is present since PHP 5.0.0. It also says about its installation on Linux:

> The common Unix distributions include binary versions of PHP that can
>   be installed. Although these binary versions are typically built with
>   support for the MySQL extensions, the extension libraries themselves
>   may need to be installed using an additional package. Check the
>   package manager that comes with your chosen distribution for
>   availability.
>
> For example, on Ubuntu the php5-mysql package installs the ext/mysql,
>   ext/mysqli, and pdo_mysql PHP extensions. On CentOS, the php-mysql
>   package also installs these three PHP extensions.
>
> Alternatively, you can compile this extension yourself. Building PHP
>   from source allows you to specify the MySQL extensions you want to
>   use, as well as your choice of client library for each extension.
>
> The MySQL Native Driver is the recommended client library option, as
>   it results in improved performance and gives access to features not
>   available when using the MySQL Client Library. Refer to What is PHP's
>   MySQL Native Driver? for a brief overview of the advantages of MySQL
>   Native Driver.

Comment: Yes it says that is present but still i am unable to find it

Comment: @JyotsnaGupta I think you need to add the extension to the ini yourself and test. If it works, you have solved the problem. If not, then you can debug and see the reason.

Comment: like creating a file as 'mysqi.ini' and entering inside this file as: extension=mysqli.so

Comment: @JyotsnaGupta are you using Apache? In that case mysqli.so might be present in the ini. Try this: php5enmod mysqli

Comment: it says command not find , yes i am using apache and mysqli.ini file is not present

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command should be just

`sudo yum install php5.3-mysql`

And it should get you working

Comment: a silly questions though...does it require to copy any mysqli package file?  and then execute this command?

Comment: tried this command. got below error : no package php5.3-mysql available

Comment: Are you sure you are using PHP5.3 version? What output do you get for `php -v`?